# Giving a sample a sample number indicating its order within a group by grouping and then assigning a number

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a large dataset containing 75 groups that vary in the number of observations, from 1 to 12. So I would like to optimize my code by grouping the data by a specific column and tell R to give it a number from 1:nrow(grouping column)

So, I tried something this but it didn't work:

```
iris_mod <- iris %>% mutate(Group = sample(1:5, 150, replace = TRUE))
iris_mod$Group <- as.factor(iris_mod$Group)
iris_mod %>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate(s_order = 1:nrow(Group))
```

What can I do to make the code recognize the grouping in nrow or what would be a better way to do this?
Thanks for the help in advanced

Comment: You need `iris_mod %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(s_order = row_number())` ?